# How to set publisher on exe file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have finished Coding my WinForms App, but when i run it as **administrator** the popup form tells me **Unknown Publisher**,
So isn't there any way to make the certify my program and make its Publisher Known.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the output code, which will guarantee that your code has not been tampered with. Here are some links that might give you some help

1. [How to: Sign Application and Deployment Manifests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx)
2. [How can I digitally sign my C# application ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84bc2159-d646-4de5-9908-2e82a4239df1/how-can-i-digitally-sign-my-c-application-?forum=csharpgeneral)
3. [Code signing certificates](https://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/code-signing-certificates)
4. [Creating Secure .NET Applications](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/05/01/creating-secure-applications.aspx) <==== very important to have a look on this link

Hope this will help you