Is there any way to include Company in cxfreeze executable exe?
I want to include company name in my exe which is python executable done by cx-freeze
I dont see any company or company_name , is there any way that I could achieve that via sample cxfreeze script.
or there is any alternative to achieve this

What company? Publisher metadata like https://stackoverflow.com/q/45403165/51685?
